# Is there a way to host Azure Worker code within an Azure Web role?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles, consolidation

I have a relatively low bandwidth Azure Web Role application and also several processes that run under a Worker Role. My worker role also spends most of its time idle as well.

Is there a way to do a Poll of something like my Worker Role loop within my Web Role?

The closest request I can find is:
http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/397209-provide-multiple-roles-per-instance?ref=title

Comment: You might want to check out this article. It shows how to combine a Worker role into an MVC app http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2011/12/how-to-combine-a-worker-role-with-a-mvc4-web-role-into-a-single-instance/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - simply add a Run() method to your Web role. Also, with Azure v1.3, you can now have more than just an http and https endpoint in your Web role, allowing you to host processes that require a tcp port, for instance.

I just [blogged](http://www.davidmakogon.com/2011/02/azure-tip-overload-your-web-role-for.html) about overloading a Web role.

Comment: Damn, that was quick. Here is the link: http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2010/12/how-to-combine-worker-and-web-role-in.html